# SI Unit of acceleration in JRowberg's MPU6050 library

Tags: c, arduino, mpu

I can't find the or don't really get what SI unit the values will have.

It's the acceleration component with gravity removed and adjusted for the world frame.

line 109 in https://github.com/jrowberg/i2cdevlib/blob/master/Arduino/MPU6050/Examples/MPU6050_DMP6/MPU6050_DMP6.ino

Answer (score 1):

The values will be in acceleration of gravity - g.

1 g = 9.80665 m/s^2.

It took quite some time, but found it [here](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=142490.15). Comment #24.

I had the same question and it took quite some time to find this.
Posibly not the best source, but it's the only note on this question I could find. I hope this will ease searches for noobs like me.

Also, the "OUTPUT_READABLE_REALACCEL" provides raw values.